# Find the plane perpendicular to the XY plane.

Tags: vectors, triangles, plane-geometry

Say I have a right triangle with the hypotenuse in quadrant 1 lying on the XY plane. How would I go about finding the vertical plane that intersects the XY plane along the hypotenuse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply find the equation of the hypotenuse $f(x,y)$ and that's the equation of your plane, since $z$ can be anything.

Comment: Thank you. I was thinking that was the case but I was unsure.

Answer (score 0):

Let the vector $v \in \mathbb{R}^3$ be the hypotenuse.  Then the normal vector to the plane that you described is $n = v \times (0, 0, 1).$  So one can describe the plane you want as $\{x \in \mathbb{R}^3 \colon x \cdot n = 0  \}$